# How to unpack an array into different arguments on method call

Tags: java

I would like to know if it is possible to unpack an Object array into separate Object on method call which accepts vargs. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062618/java-unpacking-argument-lists).

I have a code like:

```
public class Test {
    public static Object doWork(Object... objects){
        System.out.println(objects.length);
        return objects;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object res = doWork("one", "two");
        res = doWork("three", res);
    }
}
```

I would like to unpack the `res` object in the second call so it would receive an object array with length 3 instead of length 2 as now (where the second position is an Object array of length 2, having then all three arguments).

Is even that possible in Java?

---

More detailed:

By doing

```
Object res = doWork("one", "two");
res = doWork("three", res);
```

the second call gets called as:

```
doWork( Object[ "three", Object[ "one", "two" ] ] )
```

where i would like:

```
doWork(Object[ "one", "two", "three" ] )
```

I know this can be achieved by doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
res = doWork("one", "two");
    List<Object> los = Arrays.asList(res);
    los = new ArrayList<>(los);     // Can't modify an underlying array
    los.add("three");
    res = doWork(los.toArray());
}
```

But I'm looking for something like the `unpack` Lua built in function or the Python way described in the previously mentioned SO question.

---

Both answers given by @chancea and @Cyrille-ka are good and also solve the problem. One of the facts that might be a good idea to take into account is if the signature of the method can be modified.
@cyrille-ka answer respects the function's signature, whereas @chancea does not. However I think in most cases one can just write asimple wrapper function to another one, so that shouldn't be a problem.
On the other hand @chancea's way might be easier to use while programing (there no possible mistake of forgetting to call the unpack function).

Comment: Instead of unpacking you could try to make an overload method that takes an array and then the varying array `doWork(Object[] objects1, Object... objects2)` and then combine them in the method...just an idea I dont actually know if that would work for your problem.  You would have to call it like `doWork(res, "three")` instead of `doWork("three", res)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau no this is different and more in-depth than just concatenating to arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there is no syntactic sugar à la Python or Lua for that in Java, but you can create your own `unpack` method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> Object[] unpack(E... objects) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object object : objects) {
        if (object instanceof Object[]) {
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList((Object[]) object));
        }
        else{
            list.add(object);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]);
}
```

This will returns an array containing all the input elements, unpacked.

Then you can call it in your `main` method:

```
res = doWork(unpack("three", res));
```

The reason I make this method generic is that you can call it with, for example, a `String[]` array, without generating a warning. For some reason, the Java compiler thinks that this method has a chance of "polluting the heap", but it is not the case, that's why I added a `@SafeVarargs` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This does not implement the `Unpack` solution, instead it goes about it by making an `overload method` as I said in my comment.  I do not know if this at all what you wanted, but I got it to work and I felt like I would post this for reference.

```
public class Test {
    public static Object doWork(Object... objects){
        System.out.println(objects.length);
        return objects;
    }

    // this is the method that will concatenate the arrays for you
    public static Object doWork(Object[] objects1, Object... objects2){
        System.out.println(objects1.length + "+" + objects2.length);
        Object[] retval = new Object[objects1.length+objects2.length];
        System.arraycopy(objects1, 0, retval, 0, objects1.length);
        System.arraycopy(objects2, 0, retval, objects1.length, objects2.length);
        return retval;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object res = doWork("one", "two");
        res = doWork((Object[])res, "three");
        Object[] res2 = (Object[])res; // = {one, two, three}
    }
}
```

Comment: If you go that route, you can take advantage of the fact that `doWork` always returns `objects` to define it as returning `Object[]`. This way you can avoid a few casts in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return as an array of `Object` instead. Then concatenate `"three"` at the end of the returned array.