# How to pass arrayList to Tasks.whenAllSuccess(arrayList)?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating an arrayList of tasks that I want to return out of a method, which will be passed to another method that contains Tasks.whenAllSuccess().  I know that it supports multiple tasks as arguments, but it doesn't seem to want an arrayList.

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task1, task2) //this works
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(arrayList) //this does not
```

Is there any way to pack multiple tasks into a list and pass it as an argument?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What??? How is this behaviour even possible? What do you mean by "this does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(taskArrayList.toArray(new Task[taskArrayList.size()]))
```

This will unpack the ArrayList and will allow Tasks to get each task from the list.

The solution came from this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/17837497/6846268]